# Show product creation & last edit dates on Frontend in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've seen the two attributes in the MySQL database at table catalog_product_entity

the fields are 'created_at' and 'updated_at'

How do I get them to show up on frontend?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The attributed can simply be added using the getAttributeName() function, for instance, to get created_at, just add the following php script to the phtml page:

```
<?php echo $_product->getCreatedAt();?>
```

For updated_at, use:

```
<?php echo $_product->getUpdatedAt();?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are showing these two things in listing page, probably they will not be displayed.
Instead use following code:

**For Created**

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getCreatedAt();?>
```

**For Updated:**

```
<?php Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getUpdatedAt();?>
```